# Google Cloud/BigQuery/Genomics data location

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-genomics

Some of our company's work requires that data in the Cloud be stored in the US.

For Google Cloud, I can specify bucket locations to US locations. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations

But for BigQuery and Google Genomics, there's no such options in the API. Anyone know the countries where the data for these services are stored?

Answer (score 4):

By default all data in BigQuery resides in US based datacenters. We just announced the availability of an European zone, but no data will be moved there if you don't request it.

See http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2015/04/take-your-big-data-to-new-places-with-Google-BigQuery.html.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know which buckets the Google Genomics backend-server stores the data in, but if you perform the following command on their public genomics data, their buckets are all US-based:

```
$ gsutil ls -L -b gs://genomics-public-data
gs://genomics-public-data/ :
    Storage class:                  STANDARD
    Location constraint:            US
    Versioning enabled:             None
    Logging configuration:          None
    Website configuration:          None
    CORS configuration:             None
    Lifecycle configuration:        None
    ACL:                            []
    Default ACL:                    []
```

So most likely they are all US-based.

Hope it helps,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

The public data are hosted within the US. For your own data, Google Cloud Storage let's you choose the region, including US and non-US options. Felipe's information about BigQuery is correct.

For reads and variants imported into Google Genomics via the Genomics API, all data are stored only within the US while the API is in beta. We are looking for feedback from the community about data locality requirements.